# Place an image infront of a text

Tags: html

I have a title with html code:

```
<div id="site-title">
  <a rel="home" > book Journey</a>
</div>
```

No i want to insert  a small pic infront of this book journey, how can i do it.

Comment: Create 2 divs, one for text "book Journey" and another for image, give image src location, then fit to that div(height and width) depend on your requirement

Comment: assume some image with size 10 x 10 px with some source  mysite.com/1.jpg

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi If any of the answers is helpful. Will you mark it accepted?

Comment: I have gone through the answers. Thank you. All are looking fine. How to mention all are fine

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi That you have to decide which answer helps you and which is the cleanest approach!

Comment: I want one thing that the image height to be restricted to the height of the text. Is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<span>` inline elements to work with text along with images

**HTML**

```
<div id="site-title">
  <a rel="home" ><img src="imageurl"/><span>book Journey</span></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img,span{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4FDd4/1/)

Comment: can the image resize to the height of the text

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Either target image or you can target the text, so if you want to make image height same as text height you need to target image!

Comment: i could not get you. Assume this will be the size of the text #site-title {
     font-size: 45px;
     font-weight: 700;
     line-height: 100px;
 }

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi OK. Your image won't be resized with the text, you have to manually resize it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an Image tag for the link.

```
<a href="url"><img src="/path_to_img"/><span>book journey</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="site-title">
   <a rel="home" > 
     <img style="float:left;" src="path-of-your-image/image.jpg" />
     book Journey
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer you asked for ,

http://jsfiddle.net/Manjuboyz/vJS4m/133/

```
<div id="first"> 
 <div id="text"> Book Journey
</div>
<div id="img"><img src="~/Images/doctor-landing.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for above**

```
#first{
height:35px;
width:150px;
border:1px solid brown;
 }

#text{
height:30px;
width:100px;
border:1px solid black;
float:left;
}

  #img{
height:30px;
width:30px;
margin-left:110px;
border:1px solid teal;
}
```

**NOTE**:

Change the image to left or right as you needed

**UPDATE**

**Responsive Screen**

[image]

[image: Mobile device layout using media query]

Comment: My website is using responsive theme. So how to see that image size varies w.r.t the screen size

Comment: Responsive theme?? is it you are saying it is used for Devices like mobile and Tablets ?? if so , yes there is a property called "media query" and this will help you to keep the images or the css according to the Responsive screen, and syntax goes like this " @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 850px) { //Your Css properties   }" ,check out the images(posted on top) of the responsive screen you might get an idea